# java - How to convert a string to a sprite?

Tags: java, string, libgdx, sprite, converters

I need an advice for a game i am making.. I have 16 sprites that can be positioned at runtime in 43 positions. For each position I made a string that will contain the sprite that will be positioned in that position. How can i convert the string to the sprite name so i can add an action to that sprite later? If i want to add if statements to check wich of those 16 sprites is in each position will take almost 700 ifs.. Is there a way to convert a string to a sprite?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to take a look at the help page provided especially how to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please provide some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have sprite's numbered?

If yes then the simple solution is to have string hash code mod by the sprite counts. Unfortunately you need to keep a map to store which string is mapped to which sprite.

Example:

```
int spriteCount = 16:
Map strMap = new HashMap();//add type
String str = incomintStr;
int hashStr = incomingStr.hashCode();
int location = hashStr % spriteCount;//a number less than the remaining counts
map.put(str,location);
sprite[location].put(str); 
spriteCount = spriteCount -1;
```

Comment: Yes i have them numbered. I'll try this. Thank you!

Comment: Remember to use the map to avoid hashCode collisions :)